# Is there a way to display different content on mobile vs. desktop in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that uses bootstrap. It's meant to be used on mobile (it focuses heavily on geolocation from your phone's gps). I want to make the app accessible if you visit from your mobile device, but if you visit from your desktop/laptop/tablet, a message should appear stating that it's only meant for use on phones. Is this possible to do in Rails? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

[Mobile Fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu) is a rails gem that allows you to do this. You just need to check if the request is from a mobile device and subsequently render whatever you want to based on that. If you're on Rails 4 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978483/mobile-fu-for-rails-4) might be helpful too.